# spring mvc: don't redirect after login - need two models?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, modelandview

I coded a wee login controller. It has an onSubmit method which logs in the user. If the login is successful I want to show the front page without having to redirect. The front page needs content from some other model. Because my `LoginController` already `has a LoginModel` it can't also have the  `InformationModel`.

Is there some way to get a pointer on the `InformationModel`? Or some call to get the `ModelAndView` of the `InformationController`? That controller provides a `handleRequest` method.

I think this is more a fundamental question, but if you need code to answer it I will supply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I',m not sure if I get your question correctly, but

a.) You can add multiple models on your ModelAndView object. Use:

```
 modelAndView.addObject("informationModel", informationModelObject);
```

b.) If successful login, set the view to your front page view:

```
 modelAndView.setView("frontPageView");
```

To access your InformationController on your LoginController, you can autowire it =)

```
@Autowired
InformationController informationController;

    @RequestMapping( ... ) // assuming you define it here
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(... ) {
      // .. code here

      if (loginsuccess) {
          InformationModel informationModelObject = informationController.handleRequest(...);
           modelAndView.addObject("informationModel", informationModelObject);
          modelAndView.setView("frontPageView");
      }
      else {
         modelAndView.setView("loginFailView");
      }

      return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: frontPageView will be resolved to frontPageView.jsp but it then shows an empty page, because it cant access InformationModel from the InformationController. I somehow have to call InformationController.handleRequest from the LoginController.doSumbit method. InformationContoller generates the information for the front page. Understand what I mean?

Comment: i think that's the way to go. You will need to call InformationController's handleRequest because perhaps its the only part of your application that can  generate the informationModel for you.

Comment: okay, but how can I get my fingers on the InformationController? Some server internal forwarding?

Comment: thank, I found another approach using forward:main.app for the successView. This triggers some server intern redirect, without annoying the client. But your solution looks very nice as well. Which one is better? More SPRING conform?

Comment: you may check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997866/spring-mvc-forward for that question.