# Spring - How can I control the URL that's displayed for a view?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have 4 types of requests handled by 4 different methods in `AccountsController`:

1. `/accounts` Displays all the accounts
2. `/accounts/new` New accounts page
3. `/accounts/{accountId}/edit` Edit account page
4. `/accounts/{accountId}/delete` Deletes an account

`(1)` is fine. I just return the `DisplayAccounts.jsp` view.

Regarding `(2)` and `(3)`, When I take the user from initial view to `DisplayAccounts.jsp` (once the action is successful), the URL is still the old one (either `/accounts/new` or `/accounts/{accountId}/edit` respectively)

And with `(4)`, I dont have a view to start with. It's just an action, which should return the view `EditAccount.jsp` on failure and `DisplayAccounts.jsp` on success. And again, the final URL should be `/accounts/{accountId}/edit` or `/accounts` respectively.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: thanks for the question. i was having same problem today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to associate jsp with the controllers function. Just dn't return ModelAndView but void and it will call the function and wont call any view.

Comment: Oh, I dint know that. So that seems like the way to go about `(4)`. Right? And what if I bind errors? Will they show in the view? Even if I'm returning void?

Comment: Hm.. if you want to display the errors you should return ModelAndView and probably display the same jsp but with the Error Model attached. In case of error you can do `return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+url, <error model here>);`

Comment: I'll try and let you know, @Mat

Answer (score 3):

You use a forward to the new url as result of the request.

See this for an example: [Spring MVC, forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997866/spring-mvc-forward)

Comment: Do I use `return "forward:/accounts"` or `return "forward:displayAccounts"`?

What about `(4)`? I need to display the error messages on the `EditAccount.jsp` page. If I forward, I'll lose the BindingResult, won't I?

Comment: don't know the exact syntax, should be findable with a little experimentation and googling. For the errormessage: Put it in a the session or something equivalent like a database (this would be good use case for a simple but FAST nosql db)

Comment: I tried this. When I use `return "forward:/accounts"`, the URL is still `/accounts/new`. How can I get around this?

Comment: I guess I was confused. `redirect:/accounts` fixed the problem. Still confused about what `redirect` and `forward` do to the `ModelMap`, though :(