# Choose @ResponsBody Model in @RestController dependent on @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have the following method in our Spring Boot RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = USER_LOGIN_URL, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> localAuth(
            @Validated @RequestBody(required = true) AuthRequest authRequest,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String provider) {
        // ... voodoo magic ...
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new TokenResponse("abc"));
    }
```

We would like to use different request models (here the `@RequestBody` contains an custom `AuthRequest` object) depending on the value of the `@RequestParam` named `provider`in our case. Spring MVC has the [option to forward requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997866/spring-mvc-forward) unfortunately this does not work with a `@RestController` :(

Any ideas?

**Edit** - Maybe this shows a little bit better what we would like to achieve:

```
if (provider.equals("providerA")) {
    @Validated @RequestBody(required = true) AuthRequest authRequest
} else {
   @Validated @RequestBody(required = true) SomeSpecialAuthRequest authRequest
}
```

Comment: _"We would like to use different request models"_ Please, elaborate.

Comment: Found it out by myself. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@RequestMapping` annotation has a `params` property which can be very handy in that case as you can see in my examples.

Here you see the controller method triggered when the provider query string equals `"someProvider"`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, 
params = "provider=someProvider")
    public ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> localAuth(
            @Validated @RequestBody(required = true) AuthRequest authRequest,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String provider)  { ... }
```

And here the controller method called when the query parameter equals `"someOtherProvider"`. In that case I am using another request model called `SomeSpecialAuthRequest`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, 
params = "provider=someOtherProvider")
    public ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> localAuth(
            @Validated @RequestBody(required = true) SomeSpecialAuthRequest authRequest,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String provider)  { ... }
```

Comment: The second example still has `AuthRequest`. `required = true` is the default value anyway. And do you use `provider` in your new methods?

Comment: How is the params passed on ? Is it part of the headers ?

Comment: @Srikanta It's a query string like `http://example.com/auth?provider=someProvider`

Answer (score 0):

well you can do one more thing if it is just for login

Create a filter that will intercept the url and decide what type of authentication is to be performed.

in Filter's doFilter() method you can intercept the url and redirect on the basis of your custom providers.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().equals("/login") && httpServletRequest.getParameter("provider").equals("provider1")) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("auth/login1");
        } else if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().equals("/login") && httpServletRequest.getParameter("provider").equals("provider2")) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("auth/login2");
        }else {
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }
```

And make different controller methods to handle authentication.

Also remember to add `@Order(1)` to your filter.

Comment: Will `httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("auth/login1");`result in a new GET-request?

Comment: yes, but it will solve your problem, this is also how spring security success and failure handler's work

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at this.